# Agora on premises Error: 20,with stat_code:3 Stopped

Tags: linux, ubuntu, agora.io, agora, agora-cloud-recording

I am getting the agora sdk on premises error.

```
./recorder_local --appId APP_ID --channel 250 --uid 0 --channelProfile 1 --appliteDir /home/developer/public_html/api/Agora_Recording_SDK_for_Linux_FULL/bin/AgoraCoreService
```

I followed the tutorial here

[docs link](https://docs.agora.io/en/on-premise-recording/get-started/record-cmd?platform=linux-cpp#set-recording-options)

After running the command I am getting the following output.

```
Recording directory is ./20230808/250_072019_593413450/
Error: 20,with stat_code:3
Stopped
```